# Multiple Get Request Instagram API

Tags: php, json, instagram-api

I am trying to execute this code, what IT does that it get recent photos(Media ID) from current user with one GET request then based on media id it gets the likes on each photo via 2nd get request. My second get request is not executing.

```
function callInstagram($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
CURLOPT_URL => $url,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
}


$access="xxx";
$url='https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token='.$access.'';
$inst_stream = callInstagram($url);
$results = json_decode($inst_stream, true);

foreach($results['data'] as $item){

$image_id = $item['id'];

$url2='https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/'.$image_id.'likes?access_token='.$access.'';
$inst_stream2 = callInstagram($url2);
$results2 = json_decode($inst_stream2, true);

foreach($results2['data'] as $item2){
echo $image_username = $item2['username']."<br>";
}

}
```

Comment: Did you do basic debugging on your data? First check `var_dump($inst_stream)`, `var_dump($results)` to make sure the data is like you expect.

Comment: I checked basic debugging, its working fine with single query

Comment: Slash after `image_id` in `url2`